# Wpf Forms/ WebBrowser unable to retrieve the current scroll position

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am trying to get the current scroll position to determine whether it reached the scroll end or not in WebBrowser WPF Forms. I found a solution which needs to invoke a script and that is not recommended for security reasons. Is there any other way that we can able to find out the current scroll position in WebBrowser control?.